# Ubuntu 19 how to set different monitor scaling

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, 19.04, external-monitor

I have a 14 inch 4k Display on my laptop and a full hd monitor attached.
I'd like to set scaling 200 om my laptop and 100 un the monitor. How can I change the scaling separately for monitors?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028622/different-display-scale-settings-18-04

Comment: @jeff what was it?

Comment: @LeftoverSalad see the answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ubuntu 20 has fractional scaling checkbox. it can be also activated in ubuntu 19 with experimental gnome settings

Answer (score 0):

following xrandr command seems to work for me

```
xrandr  --fb 7680x2160 --output eDP-1 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 3840x0 --output HDMI-1 --scale 2x2 --panning 3840x2160+0+0
```

for explanation [Different display scale settings - 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028622/different-display-scale-settings-18-04) at the answer from travis-wayland