# Ubuntu 18.04 different scaling for bulit-in and external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a 3840x2160 built-in monitor and one external monitor on the left side with 1280x1024 resolution. The built-in monitor is perfect for me with 200% scale. However, the external monitor has the same 200% scale which everything is magnified. Is there a way to have a different scale for these monitors? (100% for the external and 200% for the built-in one.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question today, the answer from travis-wayland helped me [Different display scale settings - 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028622/different-display-scale-settings-18-04)

the xrand setting he gives is for 1600x900 monitor - you need to adjust for your resolution

here his answer:

Go to setting > displays > set scale to 200%

Connect to dell monitor, type xrandr to check for id of two monitors. Here I assume you have monitor 'HDMI-0' of 3840x2160, monitor 'HDMI-1' of 1600x900. Now I want to place 'HDMI-1' to left, 'HDMI-0' to right.

Run the following

> xrandr --dpi 276 --fb 7040x2160 --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos
>   3200x0 --output HDMI-1 --scale 2x2 --panning 3200x1800+0+0

(Note: 7040 = 3840+1600x2, 3200=1600x2, 1800=900x2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the following command and it worked perfectly:

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --scale 2x2
```

Just replace the name to your relevant screen name (in my case its DP-1).
You can check it by simply write

```
xrandr
```