# Scaling monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two monitors, one on my laptop that have the resolution 3840x2160 and one external that's 1920x1080. To be able to see anything on my laptop I need to have it at 200% scale but then everything get to big on my external screen. I have tried
`xrandr --output DVI-I-1-1 --scale 0.5x0.5` to try and scale the second monitor. This make it so the second screen is only a square at the top right instead.

I have also tried what what is explained here: [Ubuntu 18.04 different scaling for bulit-in and external monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162398/ubuntu-18-04-different-scaling-for-bulit-in-and-external-monitor) (changed the numbers of course) but this didn't scale anything correctly and when trying to get my cursor to the other screen my laptop-screen kinda moves to the left and disappears.

So, how can I scale my laptop (3840x2160) 200% but keep the external monitor (1920x1080) at 100%?

Sorry if this is a bad explanation, am very new to Ubuntu.

I have Nvidia driver 460 and Ubuntu 18.04