# Two 4k Monitors with Different Scaling Values Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: display-resolution, monitor, scaling

I'm using a Dell XPS 7590 laptop with a 4K display, and have a 4K Dell monitor attached by DisplayPort to the laptop. On the laptop, I use 200% scaling and on the external monitor I'd like to use 150% or 175% scaling. My screen 0 listed under 'xrandr' is my laptop screen, which is 'eDP-1' that I want to set at 200%. My screen 1 'DP-1' is my external monitor I want to use 175% on.

Here is the 'xrandr' output currently:

[Laptop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYb2u.png)

[External monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtvjY.png)

I referenced this thread: [Different display scale settings - 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028622/different-display-scale-settings-18-04)

Looking at the answer posted by 'travis-wayland', I'd like to do something like this but am unsure what numbers to use for my 'xrandr' command.

Can someone explain what parameters I need to change in that command to fit my purpose?

Also, I attempted using the [‘x11-randr-fractional-scaling’] setting for Gnome, which did work but I ended up with very laggy windows and bad performance on top of a mouse cursor flicker issue.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the fractional scaling of xrandr is an experimental feature at this moment, soon it will be fixed, I hope.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sadaharu. So does this mean that even explicitly giving xrandr parameters through the command line I will still experience some of the issues I had with enabling the 'x11-randr-fractional-scaling' setting for Gnome?

Comment: In other words, it is a testing version. If you are willing better and stable conditions on Xfce-like an old/traditional and non-progressive desktop, try Xubuntu or even Ubuntu Mate during the Gnome 3 desktop doesn't work as you expected. When the Unity desktop was introduced 12.04, I had a similar problem and I used a Xubuntu time to time until Unity-Ubuntu got almost perfect on 14.04, so 20.04 LTS things get better and it will be a few weeks from now.