# Cannot use full resolution of external display

Tags: display, display-resolution

I've hooked up a 3440x1440 display to my Ubuntu laptop.
The laptop detected and used the screen with a lower default resolution of 2560x1440, and no higher option available in display settings.

I've used the following commands to add the custom resolution:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "3440x1440_60.00"
```

and it does indeed add the setting to the settings screen. But when I try to apply it, it instantly switches back to 2560x1440.

This display is correctly autodetected and used at full resolution by another computer (non-Ubuntu).

I have checked that my grub conf does not contain `nomodeset`.
I have also checked that my GPU supports higher resolutions (Intel UHD Graphics 620).

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Is it possible your graphics hardware doesn't have enough firepower to drive a screen that big?

Comment: What GPU is it?

Comment: @xpusostomos my GPU is a  Intel UHD Graphics 620. According to this link, it should be sufficient: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/126789/graphics/graphics-for-8th-generation-intel-processors/intel-uhd-graphics-620.html

Comment: Have you checked all your monitor hardware options? For example, I had a similar problem today, I couldn't get full resolution until I turned off freesync using the monitors physical buttons.

Comment: @xpusostomos I did find some options in the monitor's menus, for instance I can change the way it handles the lower resolution (stretching or reduced surface); But nothing about the full res. And my other computers (a Mac and a Windows PC) can use that same screen normally without any configuration.

Comment: when I did this (the portion that i tested on my machine) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264655/running-multiple-monitors-with-different-dpi/1268083#1268083 ... xrandr ended up reporting that my resolution was 2560x1440 on my external. I wanted to hear if it worked for the question asker, to see it work on another setup before I felt confident in it. But you can play try playing with the panning like I did there.

Comment: What kind of monitor is it? I don't suppose it's a Samsung CF791.  I've had a few situation where this resolution doesn't work in Linux. One situation was using a Lenovo dock, it didn't work until I swapped to 2560x1440. The other situation was where I had freesync turned on in the monitor's menus. In that case I think it also prevented Windows from using that resolution. Do you have the ability to boot Windows and see if Windows can do it? In both cases I tried all the xrandr incantations, but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

First you don't need to use `sudo` with `xrandr`.

Second you need to run `cvt` to get the settings to pass to `xrandr --newmode`. For example (on my 4K TV):

```
cvt -v 3840 2160 56

Warning: Refresh Rate is not CVT standard (50, 60, 75 or 85Hz).
# 3840x2160 55.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 124.95 kHz; pclk: 661.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_56.00"  661.75  3840 4152 4568 5296  2160 2163 2168 2232 -hsync +vsync
```

Then copy the `Modeline` output as input for `xrandr --newmode`:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_56.00"  661.75  3840 4152 4568 5296  2160 2163 2168 2232 -hsync +vsync

X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  52
  Current serial number in output stream:  52
```

The refresh rate is too high in this case so I reduced it to 54 Hz and repeated the process.

Comment: As well as these suggestions you could also try running ctv with the reduced blanking flag which can sometimes solve issues like these, so instead of `cvt 3440 1440` you would run `cvt -r 3440 1440`. It reduces the pclk / dotclock MHz value. I don't really fully understand the tech but I believe without the flag some resolutions/refresh rates will have a higher dotclock value than the graphics adaptor or monitor can handle and reducing it can sometimes fix the issue.