# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS problem with 2K resolution on additional screen

Tags: graphics, 20.04, display, display-resolution

Currently, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and problem with the external screen (I'm using HDMI to connect).
My additional screen supports 2K resolution, but I am not able to use it. I don't have this option in the dropdown list. The highest resolution that I'm able to choose is 2560 x 1080.

The weirdest thing is that on the same machine I have also Windows 10 on that system, by deafault resolution is 2K.

I was reading many questions here about resolution problem on Ubuntu, but nothing helps me.
The next step is to reinstall the whole system.

I updated Ubuntu from 18 to 20, maybe this is problem, but on 18 it didn't work also.

Can some have any ideas about the solution? I am able to attach all the needed data.

My computer spec:

- Processor -> Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8
- Graphics -> Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
- Memory -> 16 GB

Add `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+269+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.04  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm
   2560x1080     30.00*   29.97    24.00    23.98    25.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

After added new mode with `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.04  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected 2560x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm
   2560x1080     30.00*   29.97    24.00    23.98    25.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   2560x1440_60.00  59.96
```

**EDIT**
Maybe this will be game-changer but I was able to set up 2560x1440 using

`cvt 2560 1440 30`

Comment: What is the resolution of your main monitor? Check the output of `xrandr`. And take a look at `arandr`.

Comment: According to `arandr` main monitor has 1920 x 1080. Using this application I can't set up 2K for external

Comment: Both displays are connected, and the combined virtual screen is currently 2560 x 2160. 2160 is 2 x 1080, and because both displays are 1080 high, I expect that the HDMI display is active. It may show only black, of course, if there is no window or background on it.
Are both shown in `arandr`? They should. You can rearange them, like to show the same, just for debugging.

Comment: What do you mean by rearranging them? Yes, both are in arandr, I tried to turn of main screen and stay on external but still not able to set 2K.

Comment: You can choose what you want to display with the second display, relative to the main one. Currently, the eDP-1 is is placed below HDMI-1. Yoy can place them where ever you like, relative to each other, even overlapping. Maybe move HDMI-1 to the right of eDP-1. You can move them around with the mouse in arandr. The displays show parts of a virtual screen, that is always made automatically large enough to just fit your display placing. where

Comment: Just to be sure, what exactly do you mean by "setting 2K"?

Comment: On Windows I am able to set up 2560 x 1440 and I like to do the same on Ubunut.

Comment: xrandr lists the mode 2560x1080 you like to have 2560 x 1440. That would mean pixels that are not square, or areas that are not used in the first mode. Are you sure about the second mode? I would expect the mode list shown for HDMI is probably right. Can you find where that conflict comes from? I expect that the mode under Windows is also 2560x1080. Alternatively, let me know the name of the display.

Comment: I've just check on windows I have 2560x1440 resolution. Display is ViewSonic VX3276-2K-mhd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112113/discussion-between-ice-and-volker-siegel).

Comment: There is a very similar bountied question here you should check out if you have not already: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266270/cannot-use-full-resolution-of-external-display

Comment: I tried, still now working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get access to a given mode, you typically need the following sequence of commands:

1. `cvt <width-pixels> <height-pixels>`
   You would need `cvt 2560 1440`.

   Note: [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399525&p=13812525#post13812525) from a thread linked below suggests one may have to tinker a little with parameters, different from what is returned by the "bare" `cvt` command posted above.
   If you found one set that works, you may start tinkering to adjust for the best performance. I have little experience on that.
2. Copy the second line of output, except for the leading `Modeline`, in the command `xrandr --newmode <copied parameters>`, to create the new mode.
3. Add the new mode to those available for your target display `xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 <name of new mode>`.

You should now see it as an available mode for your display, and select it.

If this works, you could automate the process of adding and selecting the mode.
In [Best place to automatically add mode in xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268678/best-place-to-automatically-add-mode-in-xrandr)
you will find a description (without `cvt`, as I had already done it at that point).
As for why the mode is not automatically detected, I wouldn't know, but it would be more of a curiosity I guess.

You could post feedback/what you get by updating your question.

**EDIT**:
Try connecting via DVI instead of HDMI.

Possibly related:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399525

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/how-to-increase-display-resolution-to-2560x1440-4175623279/

Comment: Now, I can see 2560x1440 resolution in display mode, but when I choose it and apply it, nothing changes, the screen still is on 1080 resolution. I am considering reinstallation of the whole system, maybe this will help.

Comment: @Ice - Please do these other things (see also updated answer): 
1) Check [this}(askubuntu.com/a/1103158/226614) and post feedback. 
2) Post what you get from xrandr after you selected the new resolution.
3) Try connecting with a DVI cable instead of HDMI.

Comment: I've updated the question with xrandr data. It has to work with HDMI.

Comment: Maybe this will be game-changer but I was able to set up 2560x1440 using `cvt 2560 1440 30`

Comment: @Ice - As mentioned in one of the posted links, the mode for this high resolution might require different parameters from what is returned by `cvt`. If you found one set that works, you may start tinkering to adjust for the best performance. I have little experience on that. Please see edited answer.

Comment: @Ice - As for HDMI vs DVI, it can at least help understanding how to achieve your objective, even if not providing the ultimate solution.

Comment: @Ice - Did this get you going?

Comment: Hey, I wasn't able to set up more than 30Hz, but it has to be ok for me. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Ice - Well... if that is not supported, and you have something ok, you are good to go.

Comment: The `30` should probably be part of the answer; at least, an optional part, because it is what is required for this mode on both of my (different) LG displays (and therefore probably some other monitors as well).

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i had similar problem. I have a external screen with native resolution on 1560x1080, and work perfectly with windows, but my problem was with ubuntu particulary. After try some times with the config "cvt 2560 1080 60", try to use "cvt 2560 1080 30" with the finnaly value at 30 and this work for me.

I will put my config if someone is utifully:

```
~$ cvt 2560 1080 30

~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_30.00"  106.75  2560 2640 2896 3232  1080 1083 1093 1102 -hsync +vsync

~$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1080_30.00
```